# Parse .js and .css files into master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I heard about a thing that `ASP.Net` can do a while ago, the idea was that it could put all the css and js files into the delivered request (instead of the browser having to issue new requests to get them) to cut down latency.

I don't know what its called or even what to look for.. I found some 3rd party code for minifying in VS but that's it.

What is the feature that I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to put all your css and js into the html page itself. It is best to keep it separate.

I believe the feature you're looking for. Is called Bundling and Minification.

This feature offered by Microsoft will automatically combine all your css into one and all your js into one. And it can minify the files as well. And that should help with latency.

[Here is a link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)